# Bluetooth Headphone is not detected as an output device in sound setting

Tags: ubuntu, audio, bluetooth

I am using **Ubuntu 20.04** and I have connected my wireless headphone `Sony WH-H910N` through Bluetooth.

It gets successfully connected but it is not showing as an Output Device in Sound Settings, only Speakers is detected but If I connect realme earphone with the laptop then I can see the `Headphones-Built-in-Audio` as an output device in the sound setting.

So, what should I do to show my Bluetooth headphones as an output device in the sound setting? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was the following.

Old `pulseaudio` configuration files can sometimes get corrupted or conflict with newer versions of `pulseaudio` after package / system upgrades. To fix this please follow the steps below:

- Back up `~/.config/pulse/` configuration directory to `~/.config/pulse_old/` by running the following command in the terminal:

```
mv  ~/.config/pulse/ ~/.config/pulse_old/
```

- After that, reboot your system to build new `pulseaudio` configuration files. A new `~/.config/pulse/` directory will be created automatically.
- Test your audio now.

If, somehow, **after applying this fix** you decide to go back to the previous state before applying the fix, please follow the steps below:

1. Run the following command in the terminal:

```
rm -r  ~/.config/pulse/
```

2. Run the following command in the terminal:

```
mv  ~/.config/pulse_old/ ~/.config/pulse/
```

3. Reboot your system.

However, **if all is okay and the problem is fixed**, you can remove the backed up old configuration directory `~/.config/pulse_old/` to free space ( if you wish ) by running the following command in the terminal:

```
rm -r  ~/.config/pulse_old/
```

Obtained from the following link, which has other options available: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165625/ubuntu-18-04-audio-doesnt-work-unless-i-switch-between-outputs/1165640#1165640

Answer (score 2):

A past Ask Ubuntu entry may lend you some insight: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1139404/sony-noise-cancelling-headphones-wh-1000xm2-3-and-bluetooth-initial-autoconnec

Installing bluez > 5.52 (which it seems Ubuntu 20.04 has available https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/bluez ) may provide some help.

Comment: I think that's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/whatever"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, but there is one more step.

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In the Bluetooth settings, the device name is "LE_WH-H910N (h.ear)". As you said, I have used the commands: device="/dev/LE_WH-H910N (h.ear)" and then sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device). Now, the output is showing as:   stat: cannot stat '/dev/LE_WH-H910N': No such file or directory
stat: cannot stat '(h.ear)': No such file or directory
adduser: The user `root' already exists. Could you please help ? @waltinator.

Comment: That's not the Linux device name.

Comment: It is not working. Also, I have tried to check in windows 10 on the same system but headphone is not detected in the sound setting. @waltinator